# Bash Script: Batch file rename to remove/change all characters illegal under a windows filesystem

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, batch-rename

I need an assist here, got a project going where we need to modify file & folder names within a specific directory in order to remove or replace any and all characters which would be considered illegal under Windows, with a few additional characters.
Leave final extnsion

```
ILLEGAL CHARACTERS:

    < (less than)                         MAKE -
    > (greater than)                      MAKE -
    : (colon)                             MAKE -
    " (double quote)                      REMOVE
    / (forward slash)                     MAKE -
    \ (backslash)                         MAKE -
    | (vertical bar or pipe)              MAKE -
    ? (question mark)                     REMOVE
    * (asterisk)                          REMOVE


ADDITIONAL CHARACTERS:

    REMOVE '
    REMOVE %
    REMOVE #
    REMOVE ^
    REMOVE !@#$%^&()=+][{};,`~
```

Any character with "MAKE -" next to it needs to be made a - (hyphen) in place of the character, for example a file named John\Sykes.doc needs to become John-Sykes.doc. 
If the character is flagged as "REMOVE" then it should be removed, and nothing be put in it's place, for example a file named John?Sykes.doc would become JohnSykes.doc

This is a rather important step in a very large project we have going in our organisation, and I haven't been able to create a script thus far. I know how to make simple versions, that can only change file names on a case by case basis but can't do it en mass. For example, I can create a script to remove only @ from file names, but I don't know how to include folders/directories nor do I know how to include all the other characters in this one script.

Ideally the script would run the first time and produce a file using echo with all the changes that need to be made including the full path and then the changed path. The script would then either need to be modified slightly to use mv instead, or it could refer to the file created using echo and perform all the necessary changes using it...

Any and all help would be appreciated as this is really rather important and I lack the skills at this point in time to make this myself...

A final note, I can't use the #rename command. It breaks our IT policy.

**EDIT**

I'm unable to use any version of rename, the head of my IT dept. has forbade it. I'm sure he has his reasons, but I can't say that I'm privy to them. The rename command is not available on our servers at all.

This means I have to use pure bash to perform the operation.

There aren't any additional requirements. Basically I need to be able to run a script to output all the changes that will be made to a file, before anything is changed. This will allow us to review the results and make sure there are no stuff-ups. After that, we want to run (the same script or a different one) it to actually make the changes.

All I need is stated above, so anything marked "MAKE -" needs to become a hyphen and anything marked "REMOVE" needs to just go away.

If there's anything else, please ask. I'll happily give further comment.

Comment: You say that the `rename` command *"breaks our IT policy"*. What do you mean? Does the solution have to meet any additional requirements like the language it's written in or the used commands?

Comment: Please also clarify which version of `rename` you're referring to (Perl's `rename`?), and also which other requirements you have, if any. For example are Perl / AWK ok? Are you tied to use pure Bash only?

Comment: What about `rename.ul`? Is that allowed? And would it not be easier to copy all the files over to a desktop and do it there? Otherwise I would tell that IT person to do it himself ( :) )

Comment: Nah, I'm afraid not, has to be pure bash. He'll only allow for it. And he's my boss, haha! Wish I had the authority to tell him to do it himself, but hey... this is a learning experience for me so I'm grateful for it. I'm busy specializing in linux but admittedly I'm far from an expert as yet, so I appreciate when I get a chance to broaden my knowledge.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion under my answer here, since that answer is potentially harmful and needs to be deleted. Do you need to perform this recursively or on a single directory?

Comment: @kos We're applying this script to a few directories, each containing multiple layers of sub directories. I work for a creative organisation, all work (art) is stored on a file server which is being retired. The amount of data is massive (~20TB), we want to run this script in each directory under the root share, it should apply to all sub-directories. For example \\fileshare\share contains the following directories: Share1 Share2 Share3, each directory contains 20 sub-directories, each sub-directory has another 20 and so on until we have for example 1000 sub-directories total.

Comment: Complicated. I'd rather manually add a trailing number to colliding folders / files. Something like changing the inner `if` block in choroba's answer to `j=1; while [ -e "$new.$j" ]; do ((j++)); done; mv "$old" "$new.$j"`.

Comment: @kos Thank you, I'll try it at work tomorrow and update you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script rename1.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
old=$1
new=${old//[\''"?*%#^!@$&()=+[]{};,`~']}
new=${new//['<>:\|']/-}                   # I removed /, see below.
if [[ -e $new ]] ; then
    if [[ $old != $new ]] ; then
        echo Cannot rename "$old" to "$new" - target already exists.
    fi
else
    mv "$old" "$new"
fi
```

It renames one file according to the given rules using parameter expansion. To rename a subtree, run it with `find`:

```
find /path -exec rename1.sh {} \;
```

Are you sure you want to replace `/` with `-`? It would put all the files into the same directory.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to test this now and reply with the results

Comment: For safety, you might first run it with `echo mv` instead of `mv` to check the output.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm going to do. Your help is much appreciated. I'm busy making a test directory with a bunch of meaningless files for a test bed too.

Comment: $find ./TEST/ -exec rename1.sh {} \;

find: rename1.sh: no such file or directory (x6)

there are 6 files in the directory and I'm getting that error 6 times, is it related?

Comment: Nevermind, I made a typo, it's working.... THANK YOU <3

Comment: Hmm... You do have a point, the only issue would be the size of the directory, I think we're running this on about 20TB... hence the need for a batch script... I don't think we have the capacity for a cp command.

Comment: Is there a way to run this recursively? If a directory has 6 sub folders, how can I run the script to apply to all the files in the subdirectories and the folders themselves?

Comment: @Ludicael: `find` runs recursively.

Comment: You're correct, sorry about that. Seems my GUI didn't refresh instantly, apologies.

Comment: @choroba consider looping over the arguments to the script, so that it can be called once for multiple files. Should speed things up.