# How to move data to Windows reliably?

Tags: windows, files, filename

I have a laptop which has Lubuntu installed and I have about 30-40GB of videos, documents, pictures and music files on it. I would like to move the data to another hard drive/pendrive and use it on a PC that has Windows installed. The problem is that the data on Lubunutu PC is not "Windows compatible", what I mean is the file names and paths may contain such characters that windows cannot handle (already tried it), like "?" or ":" characters (not my fault I swear). So when I would like to open a directory which contains a not "windows compatible" file or directory on windows, that directory won't be opened, I will get an error.

Of course, I know that I should correct these on a linux machine and It will work on windows, but my question is, How can I move the data to another path and also correct these problems automatically (delete or replace those characters for example)? I don't want to look through thousands of files manually, just to delete such characters, even then I could miss some of it.

Comment: You understand that with a command line method you can just replace any char by any other char? And all you need is a list of illegal chars?

Comment: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/698704/bash-script-batch-file-rename-to-remove-change-all-characters-illegal-under-a-w

Comment: Yeah, but my father also would like to use something to solve this and he will not use the command line I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a [7z-archiv](http://www.7-zip.org/) from your files on the linux-box and also extract the files on the windows box with [7z](http://www.7-zip.org/).

While extracting, 7z will rename the files and preserve file and directory timestamps.

Doing it this way, files which names cotains a backslash (`\`) will be handled unexpected:

A file named "foo\bar" will get extracted to the folder "foo" and be named "bar"

Comment: I tried it, it looks good. The special characters are replaced with "_", the slashes are deleted.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning, if you have two files and the only difference is a special character, you will be asked if you want to overwrite the first with the second. Example: file 1 "Doc?.doc", file 2 "Doc:.doc", both would be renamed as "Doc_.doc"